# Why is MIME media type application/zip not found?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, media-type

I need to return zip file in my rest Api but i receive MIME media type application/zip was not found.

```
@Produces({ "application/zip" })
    public Response convertFile(){
    .
    .
    .
    return Response.ok(result, "application/zip").build();
}
```

Comment: You need to create your own [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6791) for `application/zip` and the Java type or just use `application/octect-stream`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
@Produces("application/zip")

 return Response
            .ok(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(resultFile))
            .type("application/zip")
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"yourfile.zip\"")
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `MediaType#MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE`.

read: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html#MULTIPART_FORM_DATA

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this too.

```
@Produces("application/zip")
public File getAZipFile(){
 //your controller code which returns a file
    return file;
}
```

Note: Accept headers must be `application/zip`